# how to reduce the padding or margin without deleting it bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a doubt with the grid system, it's easy but I'm struggling for the moment, lets say that I need to do a correct implementation for the grid of bootstrap, What I'm trying to do with bootstrap is doing this example:

[image: example]

So I thought that it's very easy to do, but for some reason I'm not in the correct way or maybe yes, because with the next code:

```
<div class="container bank-payment">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bank-payment">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 image-bank">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm having this results:

[image: results of my code]

The thing is... the first one is for me the correct because it meets the condition of standards but the space between them is very long, I need to put in 8px in space for every image from right/left and bottom, but the second row meets the condition too to reduce the space but it doesn't meet the standard... so how I can solve this part ???

and here my css code:

```
.bank-payment {
      text-align: center;

      .image-bank {
        //margin-bottom: 8px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        //margin-right: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 parts of Bootstrap grid system will solve your problem:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

here you can take an example of how set the position of each column.

and probably you wont need the Display: inline-block, because the bootstrap grid system already have his way to display it correctly. If you really need an example, just let me know, but I think the links above will get it for you.

**EDIT**
It was really hard to make it exactly like you expected in Bootstrap, so I created my own classes, see if it helps you:

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <style>
        @media (max-width: 768px) {

            .center-content {
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                width: 420px;
            }

            .col-md-2_6 {
                flex: 0 0 50%;
                max-width: 50%;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 1px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }

            .devices-disappear {
                display: none;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
            }

        }

        @media (min-width: 769px) {
            .coloriz-margin {
                min-height: 28px;
                min-width: 90px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            .coloriz {
                border: 1px solid black;
                min-height: 28px;
                min-width: 90px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            img {
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                height: 28px;
                width: 90px;
            }

            .center-content {
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                width: 640px;
            }

            .col-md-2_6 {
                flex: 0 0 20%;
                max-width: 20%;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 1px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }            
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="center-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="devices-disappear col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><!-- let empty to occupy the white space--></div>
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90x28"></div>
            <div class="devices-disappear col-md-2_6 coloriz-margin"><!-- let empty to occupy the white space--></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this make the columns use the right size. 
*Keep in mind that I used the latest Bootstrap (4.0 beta)*

Comment: If it's you do not mind to help me, can you show me an example ?? cus I tried many ways but it doesn't display correctly :(

Comment: Ok, I'll build an example for you, you need exactly like the image you posted as example?

Comment: Yeah like that, and the other thing, it's important that when is in a mobile screen it only show two images per row... if seriously you don't mind to help me please please !!

Comment: I edited my answer. probably someone can have a better way to do this, but here i made something different, but it appears to work nicely for you

Comment: My answer helped you? let me know. If yes, please, mark my answer as correct and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the logos to fill the space of the column, use the class "img-responsive". It will remove the long spacing. The only issue, is that the logos will appear very large if you are using the container class with a width of 1200px or min-width of 1200px. So a better solution, is putting the row columns inside another row column with three "col-md-4" columns. Just add your logo box to the middle.

```html
<div class="container bank-payment">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="hidden-xs col-md-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28" class="img-responsive" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28" class="img-responsive" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28" class="img-responsive" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 image-bank">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x28" class="img-responsive" >
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of bootstrap especially when it comes to the grid system.  Flexbox works much better, and is a little dryer code.

```
 .bank-payment {
   display: flex;
   max-width: 490px;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
 }

 .image-bank {
   margin: 8px 4px;
 }
```

I know you were asking specifically about bootstrap, but to get your desired outcome, and do less to keep it responsive.  Remove the bootstrap classes and rows to avoid confusion.